# WPF validation - one button, multiple controls. It's anger inducing

Tags: wpf

What I want to do is the following:

I have a form with three textboxes, and one submit button. Click the submit button and the textboxes get validated - in this case checked if they are empty. Why can't I do this like in asp.net and just set a validating group that get's triggered by a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can do that in WPF starting from version 3.5 SP1. Here is an example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="BindingGroupContainer">
    <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <my:MyValidationRule />
            </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        </BindingGroup>
    </StackPanel.BindingGroup>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty1}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty2}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty3}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It is described in detail here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/11/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation.aspx